# How can I get all the href links from a single page when web scraping using Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on my first programming project.

I am currently using an XPATH method to obtain the links from a webpage, however, when the program runs it returns "[None]". Not sure why this is happening and how to solve this problem.

The href links are implemented in the html code like this:

```
<div class="fixed-recipe-card__info">
        <h3 class="fixed-recipe-card__h3">
            <a href=“xyz” data-content-provider-id="" data-internal-referrer-link="rotd" class="fixed-recipe-card__title-link ng-isolate-scope" target="_self">
                <span class="fixed-recipe-card__title-link">Title</span>≠≠
            </a>
        </h3>
```

This is the code I've tried so far:

```
        chrome_path = '/Users/name/Downloads/chromedriver'  
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
        driver.get('https://www.website.com/')

        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
 
        # scrape for links on the page

        elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3[@class='fixed-recipe-card__h3']")

        #store them in a list
        links = []

        for elem in elems:
        #fetch and store the links
           links.append(elem.get_attribute('href'))

        #remove the duplicates in list links [] 
        res = [i for n, i in enumerate(links) if i not in links[:n]]
        print (str(res))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3[@class="fixed-receipe-card__h3"]/a')
```

You're trying to get the href attribute for an h3 tag instead of the a tag.

Comment: It worked. I should've looked closer at what I was doing. Thank you SO MUCH.

Comment: No prob! Could you click the tick at the side to accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selector also:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".fixed-recipe-card__h3 [href]")
links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems]
```